# How to disable Wake on Lan

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

Windows also has *Wake on Lan* that allows a computer to be woken up from sleep; additionally, this can be disabled by a user on said computer.

I know that WoL [exists on Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wol), but how does one disable it?

Comment: Wake-on-LAN is a feature of the BIOS, not a feature of the operating system. What the OS might give you is a WOL client (the `wol` utility whose man page you link to) to wake up another machine, or a way to configure the WoL feature on this machine (by modifying BIOS configuration data).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check the setting for an interface, say eth0, with `ethtool`:

```
$ sudo ethtool eth0 | grep Wake
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
```

From the ethtool man page you can disable it with

```
$ sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol d
```

Where this gets configured depends on what you use to start your network.
[archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN) gives some examples (for turning it on, but the reverse should be clear) for netctl, systemd, nmcli (NetworkManager), and udev.